# Why is the server response after a Drag&Drop so large and slow

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I'm having some performance issues dragging cards between grids. From a backend perspective, storing the data from the grids after a change takes about 200ms.

But then, when the backend work seems to be done, it takes another 2,5 seconds for the frontend to get the response from the request. The request that's taking so long contact 2 rpc events: grid-drop and grid-dragend.

The response is also unusually large I think. Just to give you an idea, see screenshot ... notice the tiny scrollbar at the right. 
TTFB is 2,42s, download size about half a MB.

Any ideas what's going on here and how I can eliminate this?

I'm using Vaadin 21.0.4, spring boot 2.5.4.

Steps I've taken to optimise performance:

1. Optimize db query + indexing
2. Use @cacheable where possible
3. Implemented the cards using LitElement

This is the drop listener:

```java
ComponentEventListener<GridDropEvent<Task>> dropListener = event -> {
            if (dragSource != null) {
                // The item ontop or below where the source item is dropped. Used to calculate the index of the newly dropped item(s)
                Optional<Task> targetItem = event.getDropTargetItem();
                // if the item is dropped on an existing row and the dragged item contains the same items that's being dropped.
                if (targetItem.isPresent() && draggedItems.contains(targetItem.get())) {
                    return;
                }

                // Add dragged items to the grid of the target room
                Grid<Task> targetGrid = event.getSource();
                Optional<Room> room = dayPlanningView.getRoomForGrid(targetGrid);

                // The items of the target Grid. Using listdataview so this would not retrigger the query
                List<Task> targetItems = targetGrid.getListDataView().getItems().toList();

//               Calculate the position of the dropped item
                int index = targetItem.map(task -> targetItems.indexOf(task)
                                + (event.getDropLocation() == GridDropLocation.BELOW ? 1 : 0))
                        .orElse(0);

                room.ifPresent(r -> service.plan(draggedItems, r, index, dayPlanningView.getSelectedDate()));
// send event to update other users
                Optional<ScheduleUpdatedEvent> scheduleUpdatedEvent = room.map(r -> new ScheduleUpdatedEvent(PlanningMasterDetailView.this, r.getId()));
                scheduleUpdatedEvent.ifPresent(Broadcaster::broadcast);

// remove items from the source grid. using list provider so items can be removed without DB round-trip.
    productionOrderGrid.getListDataView().removeItems(draggedItems);

            }
        };
```

I'm a bit stuck now, as I'm kinda out of ideas

Thanks

[image]

Comment: How does your code look like? Which DataProvider are you using? What does drag&drop do?

Comment: I tried both the lazy approach and a List data provider. Both give same result. Also, the amount of card that I have in the grid is below a single page, the target grid contains at most 10 cards. Also, I switched to ListDataView so I could determine the drop position without having to fetch items from the db again, also I can now just remove items from the source grid reloading from db. 

The DropEvenListener is done in about 200ms and then for 3 seconds I still see the loading bar at the top.

Comment: How do you create the content of the grid? Do you use TemplateRenderer or ComponentRenderer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the TemplateRenderer/LitRenderer instead of the ComponentRenderer because the generated server-side components are affecting the performance:

Read more here: https://vaadin.com/blog/top-5-most-common-vaadin-performance-pitfalls-and-how-to-avoid-them